# How to resize correctly this image and put editText into it?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I've this problem. I want to put this layout this image:

[image]

the size of the image is 297x199. On android I want to put a black EditText into this image, like this:
[image]

but when I try to put it on my project I obtain this:
[image]

and it's impossible to add and EditText into here, with a correct size.

The xml of my project is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="EBEBF1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:text="@string/cas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/photoframe"
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="#000"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"

                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginStart="46dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to do this? Is there a correct size for this image?

Comment: You can't put anything **into** an ImageView. You can pout something **onto** it. But you can put an image as the background for a View. Including an EditText. For the "correct size", I would use a 9 patch, instead.

Comment: the only method is to resize image using for example, Photoshop?

Comment: Why not using a 9 patch?

Comment: @Rotwang how 9 patch is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I'm understanding your question correctly. I think you just want the EditText to push to the borders of your background image. For my example, I just put a 10dp margin around the EditText. Hope this helps!

```
<!--Adjust with dimensions for the dimensions of the container and image view-->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="297dp"
    android:layout_height="199dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="199dp"
        android:src="@drawable/photoframe"/>

    <!--Adjust margins as you see fit-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

You'll then insert the frame layout somewhere in your layout as you need it. ALSO: please remember that the pixel dimensions will vary based on devices and that for higher density displays, you'll have some image degradation if you don't have images for all pixel densities.